# Cannot find module 'johnny-five'?

Tags: node.js, arduino, raspberry-pi, arduino-uno, johnny-five

I am fairly new to this, so sorry if the answer is obvious.I am trying to program an Arduino Uno board to light up an LED on a breadboard it is connected to via node.js and johnny-five on a Raspberry Pi 3b+(using the rpi as a desktop). I installed node.js version 14.9.0 and through it johnny-five, I then installed the Arduino IDE and used it to download the StandardFirmata onto the Arduino board. I wrote a simple program via nano, and then ran it with `node led.js`. I then got this error message:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:895
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'johnny_five'
Require stack:
- /home/pi/led.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:964:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pi/led.js:1:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1075:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1096:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:940:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:781:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/home/pi/led.js' ]
}
```

any idea why? Help would be most appreciated. Thanks!

Output after that:

```
1598748959407 Connected /dev/ttyAMA0  
1598748969413 Device or Firmware Error A timeout occurred while connecting to the Board. 

Please check that you've properly flashed the board with the correct firmware.
See: https://github.com/rwaldron/johnny-five/wiki/Getting-Started#trouble-shooting

If connecting to a Leonardo or Leonardo clone, press the 'Reset' button on the board, wait approximately 11 seconds for complete reset, then run your program again.  
events.js:305
    throw err; // Unhandled 'error' event
    ^

Error [ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR]: Unhandled error. ({
  type: 'error',
  timestamp: 1598748969413,
  class: 'Device or Firmware Error',
  message: 'A timeout occurred while connecting to the Board. \n' +
    '\n' +
    "Please check that you've properly flashed the board with the correct firmware.\n" +
    'See: https://github.com/rwaldron/johnny-five/wiki/Getting-Started#trouble-shooting\n' +
    '\n' +
    "If connecting to a Leonardo or Leonardo clone, press the 'Reset' button on the board, wait approximately 11 seconds for complete reset, then run your program again.",
  data: null
})
    at Board.emit (events.js:303:17)
    at Board.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:486:12)
    at Board.log (/home/pi/johnny-five/lib/board.js:642:8)
    at Board.<computed> [as error] (/home/pi/johnny-five/lib/board.js:653:14)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/pi/johnny-five/lib/board.js:384:14)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7) {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR',
  context: {
    type: 'error',
    timestamp: 1598748969413,
    class: 'Device or Firmware Error',
    message: 'A timeout occurred while connecting to the Board. \n' +
      '\n' +
      "Please check that you've properly flashed the board with the correct firmware.\n" +
      'See: https://github.com/rwaldron/johnny-five/wiki/Getting-Started#trouble-shooting\n' +
      '\n' +
      "If connecting to a Leonardo or Leonardo clone, press the 'Reset' button on the board, wait approximately 11 seconds for complete reset, then run your program again.",
    data: null
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post led.js here as well?

Comment: Make sure it's `require("johnny-five")`, not `require("johnny_five")`.

Comment: Here is led.js :
```
var five = require("johnny_five");
var board = new five.Board({Port: "/dev/tty/ACM0"});

board.on("ready", function() {
  var led = new five.led(3);
  led.blink(500);
});

```

Comment: @danneu that fixed that problem(thanks!), but now this is the output:

Comment: the output is in my post

Comment: and i uploaded StandardFirmataPlus via the Arduino IDE.

Comment: The error is rather self-explanatory and not something we can troubleshoot. It's not connecting to the board and it gives you some advice in the error.

Comment: @CrazyNinjaCan15 Have you fixed an issue? Please check the port you are connecting to, it's most likely causing the issue.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the long time, it is fixed now

Answer (score 0):

You did require("johnny_five").
You are supposed to do require("johnny-five")

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the solution is "Fix the typo". This type of question has no long term value since other people with the same problem are not going to find this by searching. "Typo" is one of the standard Close Vote reasons. Answering this type of question can block the OP from deleting it to remove bloat from Stack Overflow. You can delete this answer to remove the possibility of blocking such clean up.